# Perpendicular Distance using Normal Vector

Tags: math, vector, distance, vectormath

I'm currently writing a script that determines the shortest distance from a point to a line created by two vector points. This script is going to be used in a graphics program in order to do bezier clipping, so it'll be executed thousands of times.

Due to this requirement, I'm trying to utilize a normalized line between two points so that calculating distance won't be so taxing on the user. My problem, is that my algorithm doesn't seem to work despite my efforts to fix it.

CODE

```
for i=0,4 do
    p0:Set(math.random(-100,100),math.random(-100,100))
    p1:Set(math.random(-100,100),math.random(-100,100))
    v1:Set(math.random(-100,100),math.random(-100,100))

    local NormVec = p1-p0  --determine difference between 2 vectors
    NormVec:NormMe() --normalizes vector

    local slope = NormVec.y / NormVec.x 

    local YIntercept = p0.y-slope*p0.x

    local Dist = math.abs(NormVec.y*v1.x + NormVec.x*v1.y + 
    YIntercept)
end
```

In this code, I define some random vectors p0,p1,v1. I then determine a line between p0 and p1. I normalize the line. I then find the slope and use that to find the YIntercept. I finally plug this into the formula for distance for a normalized curve, but my results are always wrong.

Info on the Perpendicular Distance can be found on the following link:
[A mathematics website regarding relevant equations](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Calculus/DistanceToLine.shtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation derivation has mistakes, so at least sign of the second summand is wrong  *(also avoid using slopes in vector calculations)*

```
 equation of line through two points:
(x-x0) / (x1-x0) = (y-y0) / (y1-y0)
(x1-x0) / dx = (y-y0) / dy
normvec = (dx / length(dx,sy), dy / length(dx,sy))
(x1-x0) / normvex.x = (y-y0) / normvec.y

(x-x0) * normvec.y = (y-y0) * normvec.x
so right equation is
x * normvec.y - y * normvec.x + (y0 * normvec.x - x0 * normvec.y) = 0
```

About distance: We need to find length of perpendicular from point `P` onto the line. This length is hypotenuse `(P-P0)` length multiplied by sine of angle, so we can uses cross-product of vector `(P-P0)` and direction unit vector `normvec` to get distance.

Quick check:

```
x0 = 4 y0 = 0 x1 = 0 y1 = 3
normvec.x = 4/5 
normvec.y =  - 3/5 
equation
x * -3/5  - y * 4/5 + 12/5 = 0
DistanceTo(4,3)  = Abs(-12/5 - 12/5 + 12/5) = 12/5

geometrical approach:
height to archimedean triangle hypotenuse 
Area = 1/2 * 3 * 4 = 1/2 * h * 5 so h = 12/5
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I still don't fully understand how the equation is derived though. It seems that you take the difference of the point you want and a point on the line. You then multiply the x,y components of this difference vector by the y,x components of the normal vector. I'm not sure why this works or why their difference is the distance. Any useful links to resources would be appreciated. Again, thank you.

Comment: I've added more description